Why Angular provider is not detectedin standalone component?
I have a component, which I will build using my custom builder. This builder builds my component in ESM format.
My component code (which will be built) is a simple standalone component which imports MyModule.
APPLICATION CODE
MyModule.ts
import { NgModule } from "@angular/core";
import { MyTestLibModule } from "my-test-lib"
@NgModule({
    exports: [
        MyTestLibModule,
    ],
    imports: [
        MyTestLibModule,
    ]
})
export default class MyModule {
}

@Component({
  standalone: true,
  imports:[MyModule]
  selector: 'lib-my-test-lib',
  templateUrl: './my-test-lib.component.html',
  styles: ``
})
export class MyTestLibComponent {

}

LIBRARY CODE
In my test lib I have simple structure like following:
I have my-test-lib.component.ts which creates MyContentComponent on demand <on click>.
@Component({
  selector: 'lib-my-test-lib',
  templateUrl: './my-test-lib.component.html',
  styles: ``
})
export class MyTestLibComponent {
  private popRef: OverlayRef;

  constructor(private overlay: Overlay, private viewContainerRef: ViewContainerRef) {
    this.popRef = this.overlay.create();
  }

  createDynamicComponent(): void {
    const portal = new ComponentPortal(MyContentComponent, this.viewContainerRef);
    let componentRef: ComponentRef<MyContentComponent> = this.popRef.attach(portal);
  }
}

MyContentComponent is empty , it has child component MyChildComponent in its HTML template
@Component({
  selector: 'app-my-content',
  templateUrl: './my-content.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./my-content.component.css']
})
export class MyContentComponent{
 // empty component
}

my-content.component.html
<app-my-child></app-my-child>

and MyChildComponent
@Component({
  selector: 'app-my-child',
  templateUrl: './my-child.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./my-child.component.css']
})
export class MyChildComponent{

  constructor(private _init: MyTestLibService) {
    console.log(this._init.someValue, 'This is value from component')
  }
}

MyTestLibService is a very simple component BUT NOT ROOT
@Injectable()
export class MyTestLibService {
  constructor() { }

  someValue: string = 'This is value from MyTestLibService'
}

In MyTestLibModule of course I add it to providers array.
import { NgModule } from "@angular/core";
import { MyTestLibModule } from "my-test-lib"
@NgModule({
    declarations:[
    MyTestLibComponent,
    MyChildComponent,
    MyContentComponent
    ]
    exports: [
        MyContentComponent,
        MyTestLibComponent,
        MyChildComponent
    ]
    providers:[MyTestLibService]
})
export default class MyTestLibModule {
}

And here I get the error. When I compile it by my custom builder the following error appears
NullInjectorError: No provider for MyTestLibService!

I have to add this service to providers of MyContentComponent to make it work...
Additionally, when I just put selector with MyContentComponent in main lib HTML it works without any issue...
Any idea why it doesn't recognize the provider when I build it to ESM?

Forgive me if I am reading this wrong, but where is your standalone component?

As far as I can tell, everything is working as expected. If your service is not providedIn: 'root', you need to provide it somewhere else. In case you have a standalone component which can be used directly without any module, you need to add it to the component's providers. https://angular.dev/guide/di/dependency-injection#providing-a-dependency

@JSONDerulo I updated the code to be more visable what's going on, just to clarify there are 3 components in lib MyTestLibComponent (when I inject MyContentComponent which inside got child component, this child component use this service)
When I put MyConentComponent in MyTestLibComponent as HTML selector, all works... even with code inside providers in module

@Grantmitchell I updated the post code to be more clear

I cannot for sure say this is your issue, however modules and standalone components do not mix, you cannot your standalone component with modules. You could use modules with non standalone components.
